# Server thread hitch warning on FiveM server

Tags: mysql, lua

I'm getting this error when i run my `FiveM` server (`fivem.net`):

[image: error]

It keeps spamming on the console and increases the spam as much as players join the server.
Sometimes the warning goes over 5000ms, making the server unplayable.

The server is running on a 4 core XEON @2.2GHz, 15GB Ram, 1GBps network (GCP), the only thing that's running on the machine is the server and XAMPP (for the mysql database).
Everything is updated (FiveM artifacts and resources).
I've tried disabling/enabling every resource and running ETW tracing (there's no high MS resource), without success.

I want to run a FiveM server without errors like this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the FiveM resources out there are created by users whom are doing this as a hobby, thus can sometime produce not efficient code. How many resources are you running? Have you tried running the server without any resources? Do you get any thread hitch warnings without them?

I have had this problem and it was with a bad resource. I removed that said resource, coded my own, and now I rarely have these messages. It is very likely this is what you are facing. Try doing the above and adding in resources one at a time to find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The problem is that i only get this warning with 10-15+ players online and i cannot test it myself, on localhost.
Any ideas on how to stress the server to test it?
Which resource was the culprit on your case?

Comment: What's the difference between the "common hitch warning" and the "server thread hitch warning"?

Comment: There's another possibilty rather than a resource bug?

Comment: I can't remember exactly which resource, I have had a few that I have found that has caused me issues. I would suggest getting together a group of people from the FiveM forums to help stress test possibly. A lot of folks on the site are fairly helpful and probably wouldn't mind helping out on that front. Haven't had the issue with common hitch warning so I cannot really speak on that front. Sure, there could be other things that could cause that. Is this a bare metal server or is it hosted by someone?

Comment: It's hosted on GCP, i don't know if it's bare metal, but i guess that's dedicated resources.
The CPU/RAM usage is always below 40%, i guess that's not the problem, maybe it's a resource, but i can't find it... Sad.

Comment: Are you using a Linux system or Windows? Could you side-load another install without any resources and see if you get that same warning?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
Do you mean another server on the same machine? On another port, without resources?

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2012. Would you suggest me another one? Linux is better?

Answer (score 0):

check resources monitor with open the console (F8) and type `resmon true`, and then see the most bigger resources consumed by which script.

Answer (score 0):

resmon is used just for monitoring msec of client scripts if you want to find unoptimized resources you can use profiler :)

Answer (score 0):

On the server console take this command :

> profiler record 25

and when you have this message [Stopped Record][image: 1] use

> profiler view

server gives you a [Browser Link][image: 2] to see all of your scripts with the time to execute. Find the issue on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the profiler to find **unoptimized resources** that take up lots of MS. Either remove them or try to make them run better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).